# Are there any side quests that can only be found by breaking and entering?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I come to new towns/cities, I always find houses that have locked doors.  My exploratory instincts tell me to pick the lock, go inside, and scope the place out.  However, what if I don't need items or gold and I am not on any Thieves' Guild quest to rob a house?  Is there the possibility to uncover new quest lines, or is there's just not much advantage to breaking into peoples' houses?

Comment: I've edited my question and flagged it for moderator attention.  No response.  What more do you want?

Comment: I am going to go ahead and just ask it again.

Comment: We're largely a self-moderated site, so there's nothing here that needs full-moderator-powers attention. This is currently sitting at 4 of 5 community votes needed to be un-held. One more and it will bump to the top of the site and be available for answering. No need to double-post (which will get removed anyway), since it is working as designed. The community approves of your changes and it's on the cusp of being put back in action!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one quest that you can get from breaking into a house in windhelm in which you can speak with [Aventus Aretino](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aventus_Aretino) whom will start the dark brotherhood quest line for you. [Here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aretino_Residence) is a photo and description of the house. Enjoy!

Comment: Most likely you will get the miscellaneous pointer quest from people around town before you have the chance to stumble upon that quest.

Comment: @kotekzot True.  You'll hear of this quest long before you get to Windhelm.  This answer is essentially useless.